# ArgumentCountError when executing indexer_clean_all_changelogs cron job

Tags: magento2, magento-cron

In Magento 2.2.6, I've encountered an issue and here is log:

```
main.CRITICAL: Error when running a cron job {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): 
Error when running a cron job at /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php:324, 
ArgumentCountError(code: 0): Too few arguments to function Magento\\Framework\\Mview\\View\\Changelog::clear(), 
0 passed in /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 58 
and exactly 1 expected at /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Mview/View/Changelog.php:116)"} []
```

This error is coming from this cron job: **indexer_clean_all_changelogs**.
But not sure how to fix this. Does anyone know how to solve it or have the same problem?